# How can I implement sugarcrm in laravel project?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5.3, sugarcrm

I have two project. There are frontend project (shop online) and backend project(crud to manage sales data etc of shop online). My project use laravel 5.3 and my database use mysql database. Both projects use the same database

I want to change my database. I want to use database sugercrm. https://www.sugarcrm.com/. And my backend project, I also want to change it using sugarcrm

So I want my database and my backend project using sugarcrm. For my frontend project keep using laravel 5.3

How do I implement it?
Whether it can be implemented?

Comment: what research have you done, what have you found, what did you try

Comment: @lagbox, I just saw the sugarcrm tutorial on youtube. I did not find the sugarcrm configuration with laravel. I ask here to see if it can be implemented

Comment: not sure what you mean by 'implement' ... if sugarcrm uses a database that is one of the ones laravel supports, you can connect to the database like any other database

Comment: @lagbox, I intend to change my database (my database using mysql). So use the sugarcrm database. Whether the database sugarcrm is mysql database? Besides my backend project also I want to replace it using application sugarcrm. Do you find a tutorial that can help?